# ManyToMany relationships with FactoryMuffin in php?

Tags: codeception

I'm using `Codeception` and I have an entity `Courier` related by a `ManyToMany` relations to `users`.

I'm using the `have` method from `DataFactory` like this

```php
$courier = $I->have(Courier::class);
$courier->addOwner($user);
```

But I would like to do it like this

```php
$courier = $I->have(Courier::class, ['owners' => [$user]]);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution

```php
$courier = $I->have(Courier::class, ["addThisOwners" => [$user1]]);
```

```php
$factory->_define(Courier::class, [
    "subject" => Faker::word(1, 5),
])->setCallback(function ($obj) {
    foreach ($obj->addThisOwners as $owner) {
        $obj->addOwner($owner);
    }
});
```